# Talking with a DJANGO server from ANDROID-STUDIO client

Tags: android, django, api, http, retrofit

i'm developing an app that the client is android studio, and the server is a rest-server built at Django.
The client communicates with Retrofit.

I want to use get-request to the prefix /api/users/{username} (That later should show me the details about this user).
With Postman all of the Http requests (Get,post,delete,put) works good. So I thought that it's not a problem with the server.

I have this API-client:

```
public class APIClient {
    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/";
//    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.github.com/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


    public static Retrofit getClient(){
        if (retrofit==null){
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        Log.i("DEBUG APIClient","CREATED CLIENT");
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

When I speak with "https://api.github.com/" (The commented line) it works great.
(So it causes me to think that this is not a problem with the client as well)...
But when I speak with my server, at "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/", the call is not getting response.

This is my server's root:

```
enter code here
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "users": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/",
    "login": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login/",
    "routes": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/routes/",
    "runs": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/runs/"
}
```

And when I send get-request for example localhost/api/users/Sammy/, 
Using the github-APi I get all of the data, but with my APi I don't get response.

Thanks alot :)

Comment: The client is Android Studio (an IDE), or the client is an Android app you're _building in_ Android Studio?

Comment: Are you running your code on an Android device (physical or emulated)? It will have its own IP address; `127.0.0.1` is the Android device's loopback address, not your server's.

Comment: The client is android app that I've build, and now I'm trying to save data on the server that I've created.

Comment: I'm using my android device (my physical galaxy s8)
127.0.0.1:8000/api is the address of my django server. It works without dependency at the android client –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP address `127.0.0.1` is a [loopback address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback#Virtual_loopback_interface). It always refers to the device where it is used. On your Android device it refers to that same Android device; on your development machine it refers to your development machine, etc.

You'll need to run your Django server on an externally visible IP address instead of (or in addition to) the loopback address. Within a local network that would commonly be a `192.168.x.y` address, though your network may not use this IP range. You'll have to modify your Android app to use that address.

In development, you can run your Django application with

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

which will cause the web server to bind to port 8000 on all available IP addresses. Then you can point your Android app at your web server's externally visible IP address, which is probably a `192.168.x.y` address if you're on the same network.

If you expect to communicate through a firewall, or make your server available on the Internet, things get trickier.

Comment: Haha I knew I missed something importent...
Can you refer me to a simple way to get started with this? 
Is it related to Amazon web services for example? 
Later on I want to submit the application at the playstore so i'm willing to invest in a good solution for this

Comment: On the Android side of things you probably want to make `BASE_URL` a configurable setting (maybe not exposed to users). That way you can modify it in development, staging, and production to point to the right place. This isn't my area of expertise.

Comment: On the Django side, in development you [can tell `runserver` to bind to a different IP address, or all available ones](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-runserver). Once you get into production you shouldn't use `runserver`; you should use a production-grade web server instead. I'm not sure how you plan to set that up, but I recommend buying a domain that you can map to your server. That provides an abstraction over IP addresses, saves you from having to buy a static IP address, and looks more professional. A domain can be helpful in development, too.

Comment: Is Amazon Web services EC2 instance is a good example for production-grade web server? 
I have some credits to use for amazon web services so I can buy some services from there for free, If someone knows which services are relevant for this.
Anyway THANKS ALOT!

Comment: EC2 is a server, but not a web server. It's analogous to your laptop, not to `runserver`. You can use EC2, but it's not the whole picture. A common solution would be to replace `runserver` with a WSGI application (which [Django sets up for you by default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/)) and Nginx or similar. Another completely different option would be to use a PAAS provider like Heroku, which abstracts OS-level and other things away for you. Push your code and you're done. There you might [use `gunicorn`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-gunicorn).